# Is it possible to change the EBS size on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

By default, creating an environment on Elastic Beanstalk spins up EC2 instances with an EBS storage of 8 GiB.

Is it possible to change this value and get a bigger EBS storage for every instance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible with the following extension

```
$ cat .ebextensions/asg.config
option_settings:
    aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
        RootVolumeType: gp2
        RootVolumeSize: "48"
```

You can get more info at - [General Options for All Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration)

P.S.
be careful if you apply these changes to current environment - all instances will be replaced